# PyCharm reporting no module found but when I go to look for it then it's there in the correct directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

My application is running in PyCharm and giving me an error saying:

```
File "/Users/Alan/PycharmProjects/anki4/qt/aqt/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
import aqt.buildinfo
```

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aqt.buildinfo'

When I hover over that line it shows this:

[image]

But I can go to the terminal and confirm it's there:

```
% cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aqt/
% ls build*

buildinfo.py    
% cat buildinfo.py
buildhash='70784154'
version='2.1.26'
```

Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its looking at this `/Users/Alan/PycharmProjects/anki4/qt/aqt/` folder ...

but that doesnt exist in that folder ...

apparently it is found here `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aqt/` ... but that doesnt matter because `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aqt/` is being shadowed by `/Users/Alan/PycharmProjects/anki4/qt/aqt/`

consider the following

```
print(sum([1,2,3,4,5])) # 15
sum = 15
print(sum([1,2,3,4,5])) # Error... because you have shadowed the builtin sum
```

the same problem exists for modules

if i have a file named os.py ... and i open a python terminal in that folder and say `import os` i will import my `os.py` not the system `os` module that i probably am actually trying to import

Comment: But that's still a problem for me as it reports no module found. Can you explain what you mean by "being shadowed"?  Does that mean they are both linked to each other?

Comment: then dont have a duplicate named module in your pycharm project ...

Comment: why do you have a package called qt and aqt located in your pycharm project? that is not  really where they typically go ... and will cause problems if you want to import from the real python site-lib package a module of the same name ...

Comment: This was what I got when I cloned this repro: https://github.com/ankitects/anki   Do you think there is something wrong with the way that's been set up?

Comment: nope you probably need to follow the directions here https://github.com/ankitects/anki/blob/master/README.development  if you want to run/build from source instead of using one of their packages ... I think as part of the build steps that file gets created (as an aside you could probably just copy the other one to your local folder but who knows what else the build steps do that you might miss)